# Change commenters email to display name

Tags: comments

wordpress's default Recent Comments widget is showing the user's email address instead of their display/first name..

get_comment_author() just changes the email address to 'anonymous'....

What do I change exactly to make it show the commenter's name instead?

```
$output .= sprintf( _x( '%1$s on %2$s', 'widgets' ),
                '' . get_comment_author_link( $comment ) . '',
                '<a href="' . esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment ) ) . '">' . 
get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '</a>'                 
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `get_comment_author_email`. See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comment_author_email) for more information.

Comment: No that gives me the email address. I'm trying to get the commenter's name to display. Nothing I try works

Comment: What if they don't fill in a name? That's probably why you get anonymous. You have to set wordpress to not accept anonymous comments then.

Comment: im still using myself to test, and my first name and/or display name isn't showing up. Just anonymous....

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, sorry I figured this out. I'm still learning WP's codex...

the following worked:

get_comment_author($comment), but it was showing old usernames after I had changed the users so that they would have user names... my bad :(